# What is the difference between Primitive data type and Non - Primitive data type in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

The lastest ECMAScript standard have 7 data types :

- Primitive :

  - Boolean.
  - null.
  - undefined.
  - String.
  - Number.
  - Symbol ( new in ECMAScript 2015 ).
- Non - Primitive :

  - Object.

So, what is the difference between Primitive data type and Non - Primitive data type ?
Many thanks for support.

Comment: See https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-terms-and-definitions : *"A primitive value is a datum that is represented directly at the lowest level of the language implementation."* and "*An object is a collection of properties and has a single prototype object. The prototype may be the null value."* . In other words, an object is a collection of other values.

Comment: Have a look here: https://medium.com/@junshengpierre/javascript-primitive-values-object-references-361cfc1cbfb0

Comment: @HereticMonkey It's the same question but got terrible answers.

Comment: Only objects can have properties.

Comment: @Bergi Feel free to answer either with a non-terrible answer and set the dupe accordingly....

Comment: Isn’t there also a non-primitive array?

Comment: @JackBashford All arrays are non-primitive values. It's just a subclass of `Object` with some special property behaviour. It's less special than function objects.

Comment: Oh, so an array is technically an object in JavaScript? I see how it’d work now — thanks @Bergi!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference between them is that Primitive data types are immutable values and Objects on the other hand are mutable.

Comment: Objects can be made immutable though. I'd say the main difference is that objects are basically collections of other values.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between primitive and non-primitive / complex data types in JavaScript is that the complex data types (array and object) can store other kinds of data - they can store both complex and primitive data types, as you can have nested / multidimensional arrays and objects, but these can both contain all primitive data types as well.

There’s a very simple way to think about that mouthful as well:

If it has brackets, it holds anything.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: What do you mean by "if it has brackets"?